# Tipos Abstractos de Datos (TAD) duda

Tags: c#

Recientemente estábamos aplicando un ejemplo con un algoritmo de pila en donde el último elemento que se agrega es el primero que sale.

Habiendo realizado esto, se nos pidió que quedara encapsulado y, por la forma que lo realizamos, surgió el problema que cuando lo usábamos utlizando de por medio un arraylist, éste todavía respondía al acceso mediante índices. Por ejemplo `[1]` (lo cual estaba mal, porque sólo tendría que responder a los métodos del TAD). Entonces se nos dió un ejemplo completo de cómo se debería hacer el encapsulamiento (que era un tema que ya habíamos visto), pero no logré entender la parte en donde se realiza el encapsulamiento con `private`.

Entiendo que se utiliza private para realizar el encapsulamiento, pero me pregunté ¿por qué no había algún ´get´ o ´set´ que se utilizara en esos casos, no?

Si alguien además de esto puede darme una definición de TAD o la forma en que éstos se usan, lo agradecería.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Pila pila = new Pila();
    pila.push(1);
    pila.push("A");
    pila.push(2);
    Console.WriteLine(pila.pop());


    Console.ReadKey();
}
public class Pila
{
    private ArrayList elementos;
    public void push(object elemento)
    {
        elementos.Add(elemento);
    }
    public object pop()
    {
        object elemento = elementos[elementos.Count - 1];
        elementos.Remove(elemento);
        return elemento;
    }
    public Pila()
    {
        elementos = new ArrayList();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El **Encapsulamiento** se puede definir como:

Una estrategia que captura la información y funciones dentro de una unidad simple (llamada clase).
Contiene y oculta la información acerca de los objetos que utiliza, por ejemplo estructuras de datos y código.

En mi opinión las ideas claves de la encapsulamiento son:

- Ocultar complejidad.
- Agrupar y relacionar datos y funciones.
- Los métodos "complicados" deben ser (en lo posible) privados.
- Las instancias de variables deben ser privadas.
- Ocultar datos y funciones innecesaria para el usuario final (de la clase).

En tu ejemplo no es necesario exponer ninguna propiedad (get/set) ya que la idea de una pila simple es implementar las acciones de poner y sacar.

Por otro lado esta pila esta implementada con un *ArrayList* pero tranquilamente podría cambiarlo por un List o un diccionario y el usuario jamas se enteraría que cambie la implementación.
Esa es la magia del Encapsulamiento.

Comment: Pero al ser el ArrayList elementos privado, como logran colocarse los elementos dentro sin la necesidad de get y set? por cierto gracias haber respondido.

Comment: El parametro del metodo push corresponde con el elemento que se quiere agregar.

Comment: Si hasta ahi lo sigo... pero al ser privado no deberia dar error? debido a que no lo esta colocando mediante un  set?

Comment: El método push es publico por lo que puede ser accedido desde afuera (la instancia de la clase).
La inclusión del elemento en el arreglo se hace dentro de la implementación del método push, es decir dentro de la clase, por ese motivo puede acceder al arreglo que es atributo privado de la clase y agregar el elemento que viene en el parametro.

Comment: Te dejo ademas la documentación microsoft sobre los modificadores de acceso a clases para entender un poco más las definiciones:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias!!!